# If-statement to not print data unless it was sorted

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio, if-statement

I have this C program almost all completed. Option 1 asks the user to enter a fraction and then option 2 displays that fraction. option 3 sorts the fractions in ascending order, option 4 finds the min, median and max of my set of fractions. However. If the user selects option 4 before sorting the fractions, then a "Please sort the values first" should pop up. I know to add the `if` statement but not sure what the statement would be.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Struct to hold fraction data
typedef struct fraction {
    int numerator, denom;
} fraction;

double Calc_Frac(fraction b) {
    return ((double)b.numerator / b.denom);
}

int main() {
    fraction arrFraction[100];

    int i = 0;
    int j;
    int num = 1;

    while (num == 1) {
        int choice;
        printf("\nPress 1 to enter a fraction\n");
        printf("Press 2 to view stored fractions\n");
        printf("Press 3 to sort fractions\n");
        printf("Press 4 to find min max median fraction\n");

        scanf("%d", &choice);

        if (choice == 1) {
            //Prompting user
            printf("\nEnter your fraction, numerator followed by denominator\n");

            //Reading values from user
            scanf("%d %d", &arrFraction[i].numerator, &arrFraction[i].denom);
            //Incrementing counter
            i++;
        }

        if (choice == 2) {
            printf("-------------------------\n");
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                printf("%d  %d/%d \n",
                       arrFraction[j].numerator / arrFraction[j].denom,
                       arrFraction[j].numerator % arrFraction[j].denom,
                       arrFraction[j].denom);
            }
            printf("\n-------------------------\n\n");
        }

        if (choice == 3) {
            int min;
            fraction tmp;

            for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                min = k;
                for (j = k + 1; j < i; j++) {
                    if (Calc_Frac(arrFraction[j]) <  Calc_Frac(arrFraction[min])) {
                        min = j;
                    }
                }
                tmp = arrFraction[k];
                arrFraction[k] = arrFraction[min];
                arrFraction[min] = tmp;
            }
        }

        if (choice == 4) {
            if (//the statement) {
                printf("please sort values first"\n);
            } else {
                printf("Min fraction is: %d %d/%d\n", 
                       arrFraction[0].numerator / arrFraction[0].denom,
                       arrFraction[0].numerator % arrFraction[0].denom,
                       arrFraction[0].denom);
                printf("Median fraction is: %d/%d\n",
                       arrFraction[i / 2].numerator,
                       arrFraction[i / 2].denom);
                printf("Max fraction is: %d %d/%d\n",
                       arrFraction[i - 1].numerator / arrFraction[i - 1].denom,
                       arrFraction[i - 1].numerator % arrFraction[i - 1].denom,
                       arrFraction[i - 1].denom);
            }
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return (0);
 }
```

Comment: yeah not sure the condition i would apply it too.

Comment: you can just create a flag (default `false`), and set it to `true` after option 3 is selected

Comment: Concur with that. and clear it whenever 1 is selected.

Comment: How would i start that?

Comment: I reformatted your code for readability: not how proper indentation and spacing and breaking long lines makes it easier to follow and understand.

Answer (score 2):

You add a flag:

```
int was_sorted = 0;
```

Then after you sorted it (inside choice 3) you set it:

```
was_sorted = 1;
```

When you modify your array you clear the flag because it might not be sorted anymore:

```
was_sorted = 0;
```

Then your condition is:

```
if(!was_sorted) {
    printf("not sorted blah blah\n");
} else ...
```

Alternatively you may write a function to check if the array is sorted or not and call that function. This would save the user from sorting the array if it was already entered in an ascending order.

Comment: How would i do it if i wanted it to print "enter your data" (if user hasn't entered data yet) and then after they enter it to print sort data first (if they haven't sorted it yet).

Comment: @airdemko3: check the value of `i`?

Comment: What do you mean by that?